# Switch between mobile or desktop template using condition in templateUrl (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular7

I want to switch between a desktop and mobile template depending on the screen width to ensure my application is responsive. I am trying to do the following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: "./" + (window.innerWidth < 768) ? "app.component.html" : "app.component.mobile.html",
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

However, this is not working. Instead of the template loading, the string, `"app.component.html"`, appears on the screen instead.

What is even more interesting is that, if I use the following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: "./" + (false) ? "app.component.html" : "app.component.mobile.html",
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

The page still only shows the string `"app.component.html"`.

Is there no support for using conditional statements as the value for the `templateUrl` field in the `@Component` decorator?

If not, what is an alternative solution I could use to achieve this level of responsiveness that is still **modular** and follows **best practices**?

**Update**: I got this to work by using `ng serve --aot` instead of just `ng serve`. However, I decided to not go through with this idea because it does not switch templates as the window resizes.

Comment: Try declaring the config object as a variable and logging it to the console, then pass it to your decorator.  I'm wondering if your scripts just aren't refreshing.  Can you also paste the contents of your two html files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your approach here is off.  Templates are assigned to components at build time, not runtime and Angular will build all of it's components, well before any window exists with a width to write a conditional off of.  You need to set up logic to tell your app when to show which component.

The "best practice" (IMO) here, if you can't do responsive design (note: it's important to understand your audience and how the app will be used. I always try to opt for a mobile first responsive design, but also recognize this isn't always appropriate), is to have 2 components, and use route guards to enforce the correct component.

```
@Injectable()
export class MobileGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate() {

    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class DesktopGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate() {

    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      this.router.navigate(['/m/']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

then define your routing structure somewhat like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [DesktopGuard],
    children: [... desktop routes ...]
  },
  {
    path: 'm',
    component: MobileAppComponent,
    canActivate: [MobileGuard],
    children: [... mobile routes ...]
  }
]
```

as for the components themselves, your mobile component just extends your non mobile component and has a different template / styles associated.

an alternative approach here is to do something like this:

```
export class WrapperAppComponent {
    isMobile: boolean;

    constructor() {
      this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
    }
}
```

with template like:

```
<desktop-app *ngIf="!isMobile"></desktop-app>
<mobile-app *ngIf="isMobile>></mobile-app>
```

but this isn't a very scalable approach and has the same "duplication" of components.

Comment: With this approach, does this mean I would need to declare twice as many routes? So, if I had a `/user` route, I would need to define a `/m/user` route and make guards for each of those as well?

Comment: so, if you have a mobile version of your site that offers the same set of functionality (or perhaps slightly reduced), maybe responsive design is the better option? The idea here is that, if you have a site that lends itself to a mobile version and a desktop version, then the mobile version should be scaled down or different enough to warrant not using responsive design (ie a significantly different subset of your features). So you'd have your set of mobile features and routes, and your set of desktop features and routes.  But the guard only goes at the top level of each router tree.

Comment: There is already some responsive design in place, but for the layout I would want, I would need to do some heavy lifting with media queries and scripting, which I would rather not do. I like this solution though, so I will try it out.

Comment: I use the same routes for both desktop and mobile, so in the `children` property for `""` and `m`, would I be putting all my routes in both places?

Comment: the mobile routes would point to the mobile components, and the desktop routes would point to the desktop components.

Answer (score 0):

If your app does a lot of stuff, then you are going to need to route to a /mobile, perhaps using the navigator.userAgent, and push the user there.

You cannot use the old 'screen width <= 768' as the iPhone XR for example has a screen width of 1792 pixels on a 5.9" wide screen, so actually it's pixel density that matters, which you cannot access.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can you do this -

```
export function getTemplateUrl() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768)
    return "app.component.html";
  else 
    return "app.component.mobile.html";
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: getTemplateUrl(),
  styleUrls:['./app.component.css']
})
```

and then compile your application using aot - **ng serve --aot** . this works with lower version of angular, I haven't tried with Angular 7 but should work.

Comment: Are you sure you want the () to call the function?

Comment: When I made the changes and ran `ng serve  --aot`, I got the following error: `ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getTemplateUrl' was called.`

Comment: not sure how this will work; read someplace that templateURL has to be static on build of the component